# Escribir datos en formulario y que se escriban en directo en la tabla

Tags: javascript, php, html5, css3

La idea es que cuando escribas los datos en el formulario se vayan escribiendo a la vez en la tabla html. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
#contenedor{
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
}
#nombrePoner{
    background-color: rosybrown;
    
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>
    
  </form>
<div id="contenedor">
    Mi nombre es 
    <div id="nombrePoner"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es la segunda vez que veo que dejas texto sin sentido al final para poder publicar la pregunta. Entiendo que la pregunta puede explicarse con pocas palabras y quizás la limitación del sitio te viene mal, pero está para propiciar que se escriban preguntas de mejor calidad (te sorprendería ver cuanto se abusa de ello). Tu acción obliga a que alguien tenga que editar tu pregunta para quitar eso. Esto seguro que si te esfuerzas un poco más, puedes añadir más texto sin hacer lo que haces, una pequeña explicación adicional, un ejemplo, algo más significativo. Si te falta inspiración, lee [ask].

Comment: Muchas gracias por decirmelo, soy nueva en stack y me fijare mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La explicación del código viene comentado en el mismo, igualmente como consejo, no hace falta que pongas todo el html y el css para ejemplificar tu pregunta.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `<form>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        
      </form>
    <div id="contenedor">
        Mi nombre es: 
        <div id="nombrePoner"></div>
    </div>`;

    let inp = document.querySelector('#exampleInputEmail1');//primero tienes que obtener el elemento del doc, en este caso, el input
    let tab = document.querySelector('#nombrePoner');//luego obten el div que quieres usar
    //en ambos he usado querySelector con la propiedad de busqueda en ID ('#loquesea')
    //si quisiera buscar clases haria ('.loquesea')

    inp.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{//iniciamos un evento de escucha dentro del input
        //cada vez que se deje de presionar una tecla (keyup) mandara la accion que corresponda entre las llaves {}
        //se puede cambiar a cada vez que es presionada, seria keydown
        tab.innerHTML = inp.value;
        //hacemos que el contenido del div seleccionado corresponda al valor del input seleccionado
        //y ya esta
    });
```